# Input/output problems

Tags: c, input, flush

```
#define MAX_COMMAND_LEN 32

char command[MAX_COMMAND_LEN];
while (1) {
    if (fgets(command, MAX_COMMAND_LEN, stdin) == NULL) {
        perror("Error: standard function fgets has failed\n");
        break;
    }

    if (command[strlen(command) -1] != '\n') {
        printf("Error: command length must be less than or equal to 30 characters\n");
        continue;
    }
    else {
         printf("Error: command not found\n");
    }

}
quit();
```

I have couple of problems which I'm not able to handle:

1. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it stops the loop and doesn't print the `command not found` message.
2. When I enter a command with a size bigger than 30 characters it prints both the `command not found` and the `command length must be less than or equal to 30 characters` messages.
3. When I enter a 64 size command it prints twice the 30-length message.

I believe it divides the input to 30-length segments and input each one of them, how do I overcome it? I tried to flush `stdin`, it does not work. I want to get rid of the rest of the input. How do I overcome all these problems?

Comment: Don't try to flush stdin, it invokes UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second problem, it's because `fgets` fetches the 31 (`MAX_COMMAND_LEN`, minus space for the terminating `'\0'` character) first characters, you notice it's no newline and the next time around the loop `fgets` fetches the remaining characters.

Comment: Actually `fgets` fetches only 31 `char`s. It reserves room for `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

> When I enter a command with a size bigger than 30 characters it prints both the 'command not found' and the 'command length must be less than or equal to 30 characters' messages.

`fgets` reads a maximum of `MAX_COMMAND_LEN - 1` characters as it leaves room for a `'\0'`.
This is why for any message of more than 30 character, the first 31 characters that `fgets` reads don't contain a `'\n'` and so the 30-length message is displayed.
As the second part of the command has a `'\n'` in the end, the `command not found` is also printed.

> When I enter a 64 size command it prints twice the 30-length message.

`fgets` is called 3 times for this command. The first 31-length chunk is read, then the second 31-length chunk is read, and then the remaining characters. Both 31-length chunks don't contain a `'\n'` character and therefore the 30-length message is displayed twice.

Answer (score 1):

You may have misunderstood how `fgets` actually [works](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/):

> `char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );`
>   Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str
>   until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the
>   End-of-File is reached, whichever comes first.  A newline character
>   makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character and
>   therefore it is included in the string copied to str.  A null
>   character is automatically appended in str after the characters read
>   to signal the end of the C string.

So,

1. when you press "Enter" - it inputs newline and that is not exceptional case in your code.
2. when you input a string bigger than 30 characters `fget` reads it for multiple times.
3. same with the 60 characters - newline is NOT the last character of the string, thus you get an error twice.

Answer (score 1):

For question (i), sorry, I don't know why, because my program gives the correct output.

For question (ii), you give the second argument of fgets is 32, the function will read at most 32 characters including the '\n' and '\0'; what's left is still in the stdin buffer, and when your program continues after printing the error, the fgets will read the leftover characters in the stdin buffer until it reads '\n'.

If you want to flush the stdin, you need `fpurge(stdin)` function to purge the stdin buffer.